# Using all the dates in a given table

Tags: c#, sql-server, date

I've been currently working on a stored procedure that grabs all the clients I have in the database that have loans. How I'm filtering the results is by the start and end dates given when generating the data. The way my data works is that the returned table will have multiple date fields, 9 date fields to be precise. Each of these date fields are used depending on the `LoanStatus` field that is also a part of this table. `LoanStatus` can have values such as `Settled`, `Approved`, `Cancelled`.. What I want to do is to filter the results using this start and end date but applying it to all of the date fields

In my head I've got a couple of pseudo ways to possibly work this issue out:

**First Possible Solution**

Need some code that'll allows me to essentially do this:

```
allDatefields > @startDate AND allDatefields < @endDate.
```

**Second Possible Solution**

Is to only take into consideration the date field that matches with the loan status. For example, if the `LoanStatus` is Settled, then look at the `DateSettled` column of the table, or if the `LoanStatus` is Approved, then look at the `ApprovalDate` column of the database.

Personally, I would love to be able to filter through and apply the `@startDate` and `@endDate` to all date fields rather than have to look at each date seperately.

Is there a way in SQL Server to apply a `WHERE` clause to all date fields in a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, the where clause does not support your first scenario. I think you might have to settle for something like this:

```
(LoanStatus = 'Approved' and ApprovalDate > @startDate AND ApprovalDate < @endDate) OR (LoanStatus = 'Settled' and SettleDate > @startDate AND SettleDate < @endDate) OR ... same for the rest of loan status values
```

Comment: yeah you're right. I've been searching online while waiting for an answer here and came to the same conclusion. I've done something quite similar to what you've provided to get what I want. I will put yours as the accepted answer :).